# Angular: How to use a custom component to keep forms DRY?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form inside a component, like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="edit">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="{{componentId}}_iptItemName" class="col-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-8">
      <input id="{{componentId}}_iptItemName" type="text" class="form-control"
             formControlName="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more form groups -->
</form>
```

Most of the fields look the same, so I would like to take the `div.form-group` and make a reusable component. The problem is, I can't get the `formControlName` into the nested component.

When I try just specifying `formControlName` on the new component, I get:

> No value accessor for form control with name: 'name'

When I use an `@Input() appFormControlName: string` and pass that value to the `input`'s `[formControlName]`, I get:

> formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

I've seen things where I could [create an extra form group for each nested component](https://jenniferwadella.com/blog/nested-angular-reactive-forms), or [register some kind of custom `ControlValueAccessor` to make it a "true" form control](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html), but both of those seem overly complicated for what I'm doing. I just want to create a component to keep things DRY, not add complexity by creating custom form controls or kludge in single-value form groups.

Am I just missing something simple?

Comment: If you need a custom component to act as a normal formControl, you’ll need to go the controlValueAccesor route. Which really is not very complex..

Comment: You have to pass formControl to child component and have to use standalone formControl directive to make it work. some think like this [formControl]="appFormControlName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `<ng-content>` and just keeping the input in the form component.

```
<app-card-input label="Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name"/>
</app-card-input>
```

I also set up the component to create the `id`s on the fly:

```
let next = 0;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-input',
  templateUrl: './card-input.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class CardInputComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() label: string;
  componentId = `app-card-input-id-${next++}`;

  constructor(private elr: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const ipt = this.elr.nativeElement.querySelector('input, select, textarea');
    ipt.setAttribute('id', this.componentId);
  }

}
```

I mostly decided to go this route because it gives me the flexibility to use different control types. I will need `checkbox`es, `texarea`s, and other controls, and having separate `ControlValueAccessor`s for each (or trying to cram them all under one) could get cumbersome.

Thanks @Petr and @Bojan for your answers. They definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

ControlValueAccessor seems complicated at first, but exactly what you need. It will solve many problems later.
It's quite easy to use it, just a lot of "boilerplate".

Comment: I'll head down this road and give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer** just name component input differently e.g. `@Input() myFormControlName`

**Long answer** There is a difference between (as I call them) "custom component" and "custom control". When writing custom component avoid "standard" names for Input, Output such as ngModel, formControl, formControlName, etc. And usage looks like:

```
<my-component [myData]="data" (myDataChange)="change()">
```

or you may pass formControl/formGroup or whatever:

```
<my-component [myFormGroup]="someFormGroup" "myControlName"="someControlName">
// 'myControlName' IS @Input of component
```

As for "custom control" I'll give you https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/checkbox/checkbox.ts as an example.
And usage is:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</mat-checkbox>
```

or

```
 <mat-checkbox formControlName="checkBoxName">Checked</mat-checkbox>
 // 'formControlName' IS NOT @Input of component
```